# Generating a Gaussian point spread function using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, gaussian

I wrote this function to generate a Gaussian point spread function using Python, I wonder if my approach is correct or needs modification.

I wrote this function, but not sure if my approach is correct:

```
def generate_PSF(size, sigma):
    """
    Generates a  Gaussian Point Spread Function (PSF).
    """
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-size/2, size/2, size), np.linspace(-size/2, size/2, size))
    d = np.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    psf = np.exp(-d**2 / (2*sigma**2))
    psf /= np.sum(psf)  # Normalize the PSF
    return psf
```

Comment: You might want to use `size//2`, and verify that `size` is odd. Also, don’t take the square root if you’re going to square the result again right after. Oh, and you don’t really need `meshgrid`… Other than that, if it produces the right result, you’re doing it OK. I personally prefer computing `size` from `sigma`, to avoid user error. [Too many times have I seen people use a sigma that is too large for their chosen size.](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695/)

Comment: @CrisLuengo, could you please modify the code to show what you explained? I could better understand. I could not understand